# XPath Class is and Text Contains

Tags: python, xpath

I've been slowly getting better at XPATH but every time I think I have it (at least at a basic level) something which I thought was obvious decides to throw me.

Trying to click a list item:

```
<li class="league_check " id="lg_chk_br_1_l_22953" onclick="BranchWindow.showLeague(1,22953);"> <img leagueid="22953" src="/i/none_v.gif" width="12" height="12" onclick="BranchWindow.switchLeague(1,22953); cancelBubble(event);">Champions League </li>
```

With this:

```
eachleague = "Champions League"
link = Driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'league_check ') and text() = '%s']" % eachleague)
```

I'm double checking everything has actually loaded etc... And (to my understanding of XPATH) this should be finding the list item.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can blame the *extra space* inside the text. Either normalize:

```
//li[contains(@class, 'league_check ') and normalize-space(.) = '%s']" % eachleague
```

Or, use `contains()`:

```
//li[contains(@class, 'league_check ') and contains(., '%s')]" % eachleague
```

And, since you are using `contains` for the `class` attribute, you may remove that trailing space after the `league_check`.

---

Alternatively, you may rely on the "league id"s, something like:

```
leagues = {
    "Champions League": 22953,
    # more leagues
}
league_id = leagues[eachleague]
link = Driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'league_check') and img/@leagueid = '%d']" % league_id)
```

Comment: Apparently there is a limit on how quickly I can accept an answer. I guess that is a sign that I really shouldn't of had to ask. But that's perfect I wish I'd spotted it. Thanks for taking the time!